# Liquid button animation in React Native

Tags: react-native, animation, svg, react-native-reanimated

Is it possible to achieve this kind of animation for custom control in React Native using reanimated and SVG?

[image]

Comment: Here I suggest one library, It's not what you want but you can customize by adding condition based on your purpose: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-liquid-progress

Answer (score 2):

yes. you can achieve this with Lottie animation. this is the package for this. [lottie-react-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lottie-react-native). you can find some sample animation [here](https://iconscout.com/lottie-pack/liquid-toggle). for ask your designer to design a custom animation like this.